# i m trying to get the value of array from post

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to find the row ID  of the textbox when blur is triggered, but I couldn't make it work so far.

All I need is something like `#employee_0` in `form_data` when the blur event is triggered on my first textbox.

```
$("input").blur(function () {

    $('input').each(function (index, value) {

        var form_data = $("#employee_" + index).find('input').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url("HomeController / calculate_time_lap "); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function (result) {
                $('input').closest('tr').find('.TextBox3').val(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and here is my view page:

```
<tr id="employee_0"><input type ="textbox"></tr>
<tr id="employee_1"><input type ="textbox"></tr>
<tr id="employee_2"><input type ="textbox"></tr>
<tr id="employee_3"><input type ="textbox"></tr>
<tr id="employee_4"><input type ="textbox"></tr>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so that other people can read it and help you. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with this AJAX, but note that as written with that `.each()` call it'll cause an AJAX post for _every_ `input` element any time you trigger a `.blur` on _any_ `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

Within the event handler the row ID will be available as:

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Note that your HTML isn't legal - you need `<td>` elements inside the `<tr>`.

If, instead, you're just trying to find (and serialise) all of the inputs that are in the same row, you don't actually need the ID at all, you can just traverse the DOM from where you are:

```
$("input").blur(function () {
    var form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize();
    $.ajax(...);
});
```

Comment: I think what the OP actually wants is `var form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize();` but the question is a bit vague. He might have just asked for the ID because he thinks he needs it to select all the inputs.

Comment: @FelixKling it is indeed vague.  He has explicitly asked for the "row ID", yet it would seem he needs the input's value.  XY problem?

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize(); thank u this was i exactly waiting for - Felix Kling 48 ...thank u very much

Comment: @user2206616 how many inputs are there in each row?  If there's only one you only need `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: inputs are in array .so it worked for every inputs $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serialize();

Answer (score 0):

*find the row -id of textbox when blur is triggred*

```
$("input").blur(function() {
  var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
  // some more stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just use .parent(), then you can get tr, also can get tr's id.

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));  
});
```